# Probability of conditional distribution is uniform(0,1)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Define the conditional distribution function of $X$ on $Y$ as
\begin{align*}
F(x) := \mathbb{P}(X \leq x | Y)
\end{align*}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. How do I show that $F(X)$ conditional on $Y$ is distributed Uniform(0,1), in other words, for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(F(X) \leq \alpha | Y) = \alpha
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We know that $F(X)$ is a uniform$(0,1)$ random variable, so to have $\mathbb{P}(F(X)\le \alpha|Y)=\alpha=\mathbb{P}(F(X)\le \alpha)$, we must have $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Conversely, of $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the conditional distribution has to be Uniform$(0,1)$ by definition.

Comment: I have two questions: first of all, how do I know that F(X) is indeed uniform? In the usual case when it’s unconditional, I know it is uniform, but in this case we are conditioning on Y, so that may not be the case. For the second question: why is independence necessary for $\mathbb{P}(F(X) \leq \alpha| Y) = \alpha = \mathbb{P} (F(X) \leq \alpha)$?

Comment: Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A|B)=P(A)$. Since in the unconditional case we know that $F(X)$ is uniform, so we already have $P(F(X)\le \alpha)=\alpha$, hence we will have $P(F(X)\le\alpha)=P(F(X)\le\alpha|Y)$, which implies independence, by the definition just mentioned above.